# java mail - processing csv attachment

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I am receiving e-mails set from a normal GUI client such as thunderbird or outlook, which conntain message body as String and one csv file attachment.

Using Java mail I would like to process the attachment i.e. read in the contet of the csv file into a String. Can I simply check whether the contet is a Multipart and then process the one at index 1 ( I guess e-mail body is at index 0)? Or should I check for dispositions which flags which part is an attachment? My only cocern is that if oe seds an e-mail using a regular GUI client, these flags are not set...

Any comments on what approach to take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This JavaMail FAQ entry](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#readattach) will help.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Javamail tutorial](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/JavaMail/contents.html#GettingAttachments)

> The content of your message is a Multipart object when it has
>   attachments.  You then need to process each Part, to get the main
>   content and the attachment(s).  Parts marked with a disposition of
>   Part.ATTACHMENT from part.getDisposition()  are clearly attachments...